# R read.xlsx only specifying some columns ColClasses

Tags: r

I have an excel sheet with 50 columns.

How would I be able to only specify the colClass of a single attribute when using read.xlsx, without specifying the colClasses of all the attributes?

I tried

```
    read.xlsx(data.xlsx, colClasses=c("Test A"= "character"))
```

but receive the error message:

unused argument (colClasses = c("Test A" = "character"))

Thank you!

Comment: If the funciton is from `openxlsx`, it doesn't have that argument.  With `readxl` there is `col_types` for `read_excel` function

Comment: Can't you just create a vector with NULL in the remaining positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `read_xlsx()` from `readxl`

```
library(readxl)
read_xlsx(data.xlsx, col_types=c("text"))
```

col_types vector can be populated with "guess" for all other columns.

More details about col_types:

> Either NULL to guess all from the spreadsheet or a character vector
>   containing one entry per column from these options: "skip", "guess",
>   "logical", "numeric", "date", "text" or "list". If exactly one
>   col_type is specified, it will be recycled. The content of a cell in a
>   skipped column is never read and that column will not appear in the
>   data frame output. A list cell loads a column as a list of length 1
>   vectors, which are typed using the type guessing logic from col_types
>   = NULL, but on a cell-by-cell basis.